# problema con hilos al imprimir en un Datagrivie

Tags: c#, visual-studio

hola buenas alguien podria ayudarme a resolver este error, tengo un primer dataGrivie que muestra todos los clientes combinados femenimos y masculinos luego ago los hilos para sacar todos los clientes y dividirnos en femenimos y masculinos en dos data diferentes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pasa que intento imprimir en dos dataGriview solo clientes con sexo femenimo y en otro solo masculinos pero me sale este error mi codigo es este.

```
 public void leerGeneroFemenino()
        {
            Object[] fila = new Object[6];

            for (int i = 0; i < clientes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (clientes[i] != null)
                {

                    if (clientes[i].Genero == 'F')
                    {

                        fila[0] = clientes[i].Identificador;
                        fila[1] = clientes[i].Nombre;
                        fila[2] = clientes[i].PrimerApellido;
                        fila[3] = clientes[i].SegundoApellido;
                        fila[4] = clientes[i].FechaNacimiento;
                        fila[5] = clientes[i].Genero;


                        dataGridView2_Mujeres.Rows.Add(fila);

                        

                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

este es mi metodo que saca de mi vector solo los de sexo femenimo y los ingresa en un datagriview

y este es el hilo que ejecuto en un boton

```
Thread hilo_Mujeres = new Thread(leerGeneroFemenino);
                  hilo_Mujeres.Start();
```

me comentarian como podria resolver este problema, acaso es que no puedo hacer el proceso y imprimir al mismo tiempo en el data? deberia hacer el proceso con el hilo y hasta despues ingresarlo al dataGrivie o como podria resolver este problema ?

Comment: Si se puede.. tenes que usar un invoke... cuando pueda, lo respondo...

Comment: ok gracias, cuando puedas me respondes, porque asi no me uvico

Comment: bueno.. tambien podes buscar invoke por internet no?

Comment: si tambien pero si pregunte por aqui es para que talves alguien me comparta algo mas apegado ami problema, entonces gracias por la sujerencia pero igual esperare a ver si alguien me responde ya que realmente tampoco entiendo porque la exepcion se produce en el data porque alli es donde me la marca

Comment: entonces gracias igual por la sujerencia lo googleare para mietras me responden

Comment: talves googleandolo esto que comentas lo resuelva , igual esperare aqui sino le llego leyendo